# How does Graphics work for group of images

Tags: graphics

```
Import["img.tiff"];
Show[Colorize[ImageAdjust[%, 0, {.00000002, .00000009}],ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
ColorFunctionScaling -> True], Graphics[{Cyan, Thickness -> .003,
Line[{{736.7 + 70*Cos[45*Pi/180],589.5 + 70*Sin[45*Pi/180]}, 
{736.7 + 550*Cos[45*Pi/180],589.5 + 550*Sin[45*Pi/180]}}],Line[{{736.7 + 70*Cos[135*Pi/180], 
589.5 + 70*Sin[135*Pi/180]},{736.7+550*Cos[135*Pi/180],589.5+550*Sin[135*Pi/180]}}],Circle[{736.7, 589.5}, 70, {45*Pi/180, 135*Pi/180}],
Circle[{736.7, 589.5}, 550, {45*Pi/180, 135*Pi/180}]}],
ImageSize -> 400]
```

`img.tiff` can be downloaded from [my google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cW2ZXqxNyWbtkcDq6LEKQFXiS5olQjRJ/view?usp=sharing).

I did this one only for one image, but I want to do same thing for group of images. I want to do same thing for group of images. And images should be display each other

[image]

Comment: The code is syntactically incorrect as many pink brackets and braces in the notebook should indicate to you. Lacking a further description, I cannot tell what you try to achieve here.

Comment: @Henrik I try to fixed and edit my question, also I publish what I did, but I could not do same thing for group of images

Comment: How is the 'group of images' specified? You can `Map` your procedure on a list of urls or `Table`. Also, better use `img = Import[...` and use it rather than `%`.

Comment: @Kuba I can import group of images(more then one pictures) by using Map. Problem is apply this graphics to all of those import images together.

Comment: Do you want to display several images next to each other? Perhaps you should check out `Inset` which allows to place them in the same `Graphics`. Also the first argument of `Show` should be a list of `Graphics` you want to combine, although it often works the way you have used.

Comment: I agree, the moment it is a bit unclear what to you want to achive in the end. Maybe you can show us an example of how it should look like in the end.

Comment: @Johu yes I want display several images next to each other

Comment: @Johu I uploaded one image that I did, now I want to do same thing with group of images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, the goal is to take several images, add a same `Graphcis` to each one of them and dipslay them all next to each other. Maybe it is not exactly what you need, but perhaps it gets you started and shows you a the *Mathematica* style a bit.

First I import multiple images

```
filenamelist = {
   "DTC5C9_Dimer_cool_T127.891C_30.00s_444875_saxs.tiff",
   "DTC5C9_Dimer_cool_T127.891C_30.00s_444875_saxs.tiff",
   "DTC5C9_Dimer_cool_T127.891C_30.00s_444875_saxs.tiff"
   };
imgList = Import /@ filenamelist;
```

then I manipulate and overlay each one of them before displaying them in a `Row`

```
overlay = 
  Graphics[{Cyan, Thickness -> .003, 
    Line[{{736.7 + 70*Cos[45*Pi/180], 
       589.5 + 70*Sin[45*Pi/180]}, {736.7 + 550*Cos[45*Pi/180], 
       589.5 + 550*Sin[45*Pi/180]}}], 
    Line[{{736.7 + 70*Cos[135*Pi/180], 
       589.5 + 70*Sin[135*Pi/180]}, {736.7 + 550*Cos[135*Pi/180], 
       589.5 + 550*Sin[135*Pi/180]}}], 
    Circle[{736.7, 589.5}, 70, {45*Pi/180, 135*Pi/180}], 
    Circle[{736.7, 589.5}, 550, {45*Pi/180, 135*Pi/180}]}];
myColors = 
  Colorize[ImageAdjust[#, 0, {.00000002, .00000009}], 
    ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", ColorFunctionScaling -> True] &;
Row@Table[

 Show[{myColors@img, overlay}, ImageSize -> 400], {img, imgList}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking exactly like this.